# Json Parsing Issue

Tags: apex, community, rest-api, json, parser

I am trying to parse json response as follows:

```
["India",["India","India\u2013United States Civil Nuclear Agreement","Indian rupee"],["India, Test"],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93United_States_Civil_Nuclear_Agreement"]]
```

Wrapper class:

```
public class fromJSON{
public String Text;    //India
public List<jsonTitles> jsonTitles;
public List<jsonDetails> jsonDetails;
public List<jsonURL> jsonURL;
public class jsonTitles{}
public class jsonDetails{}
public class jsonURL{}
public static fromJSON parse(String responseBody ){
System.debug('@@@@@@@' +JSON.deserialize(responseBody , fromJSON.class));
return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(responseBody , fromJSON.class);
}  
}
```

I am unbale to do as I land up with this error

```
Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object
```

I have concatenated json string to solve this issue I am getting following error after that:

```
System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('[line:1, column:3]
```

What I can understand from JSON is, it is in array with out key value pairs.

I have used deserialize methods of salesforce but unable to do this.Can anyone help me with snippet or the approach.??

But I am able to do with javascript: If JSON validator says it is valid response.Then with apex I should be able to do it??

How it is possible using JavaScript:

```
parseResult : function(res,helper){
        var retJSON = JSON.parse(res);
        var jsonTitles = retJSON[1] ; 
        var jsonDetails = retJSON[2];
        var jsonURL = retJSON[3];

        var domSearch = document.getElementById('resultPlaceHolder');
        while (domSearch.firstChild) {
            domSearch.removeChild(domSearch.firstChild);
        }

        for(var i=0 ; i<jsonTitles.length ; i++)
        {
           helper.createChildNodes(domSearch, jsonTitles[i],jsonDetails[i],jsonURL[i]); 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two resource that will help you out tremendously here:

- [JSON](http://www.json.org/) - understand the spec
- [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - validate specific payloads
- [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) - verify corresponding `Apex`

Your payload is not in a valid format for several reasons. Here is the immediate JSONLint Result:

> Results
>
> > Error: Parse error on line 3:
> > ...Nuclear_Agreement", ]]
> > -----------------------^
> > Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ']'

Your first problem you have is that you have a comma which is not followed by a subsequent list element. Lists are of the format:

```
[element1, element2, element3]
```

However, you have left a dangling comma:

```
[element1,]
```

Note the JSON spec on arrays:

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
>
> [image: array spec]

---

Once you fix the above issue, your work is not done. If you want to deserialize this data structure into an `Apex Class`, it won't work. You also need to understand the object structure:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace). Each name is followed by `:` (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (comma).
>
> [image: object spec]

These keys will correspond to the properties in your class. So a properly formatted object would look like:

```
{
    "Text": "India",
    "jsonTitles": ["..."],
    "jsonDetails": ["..."],
    "jsonUrl": ["..."]
}
```

Change your `jsonTitles`, `jsonDetails`, and `jsonUrl` properties to the `List<String>` type. The custom classes you have defined cannot be serialized into anything useful.

If you plug this last payload into [`JSON2Apex`](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/), you'll get a simple class that should work for your needs:

> ```
> //
> // Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
> //
>
> public class JSON2Apex {
>
>   public String Text;
>   public List<String> jsonTitles;
>   public List<String> jsonDetails;
>   public List<String> jsonUrl;
>
>   
>   public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
>       return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
>   }
> }
> ```

---

If you really want to stick with this poorly structured JSON format, you can use `deserializeUntyped` to get something workable:

```
List<Object> data = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
List<String> jsonTitles = (List<String>)data[1];
List<String> jsonDetails = (List<String>)data[1];
List<String> jsonURL = (List<String>)data[1];
```

Comment: It is valid now you can check..removed comma from json response ..

Comment: It was manual error from my end.But I am unable to parse the response

Comment: See updated answer. You can't deserialize an array of different types into an object. You need to actually specify the keys.

Comment: Updated question as well